# Completing text based on another table

Tags: mysql, string, text

I have a table which uses external data that arrives cut off. Can I complete it from tables that aren't cut off (as they use alternative external data)?

In this example, the 2nd and 3rd rows can be completed using the matching data from their respective tables.

```
Table1:
Table | Type | Description
   X  |  A   | A long line th
   X  |  B   | A long line th
   Y  |  B   | This line d
   Y  |  A   | This line d

TableX:
Type | Description
  A  | A very long line that doesn't get cut off
  B  | A long line that doesn't get cut off

TableY:
Type | Description
  A  | just a long line that doesn't get cut off
  B  | This line doesn't get cut off

Needed result
===============
Table1:
Project | Type | Description
   X    |  A   | A long line th
   X    |  B   | A long line that doesn't get cut off
   Y    |  B   | This line doesn't get cut off
   Y    |  A   | This line d
```

Comment: What do you want to do when you have "A long line th" and "A long line that is not cut off" or "A long line that is even longer and not cut off." as possible matches? If it doesn't matter, you can just do a simple update where `source.Description like dest.description+'%';`

Comment: looks like if Type is A you grab description from Table1 and Type is B you grab description from Table[Project] (TableX,TableY) is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

To complete rows you can select and update Description.

```
update Table1 set Description = (select Description from TableX where Description LIKE 'A long line th%' limit 1); 

update Table1 set Description = (select Description from TableY where Description LIKE 'This line d%' limit 1);
```

To select without update table you can

```
select tb1.Table as Proyect, tb1.Type, (select Description from TableX where Description like CONCAT(tb1.Description,'%')) from Table1 tb1 where tb1.Table = 'X'
UNION
select tb1.Table as Proyect, tb1.Type, (select Description from TableY where Description like CONCAT(tb1.Description,'%')) from Table1 tb1 where tb1.Table = 'Y';
```

And this maybe can help someone,

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (
select 'X' as Project, Type, Description from Table1
UNION
select 'Y' as Project, Type, Description from Table2);
```

Maybe your Table1.Description is wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY COLUMN Description varchar(200);
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't acknowledge that it's not just description but "Type + description" (the Type was A & B in the example).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```
SELECT `Table` as Project,Type,Description
FROM Table1 T1 WHERE Type = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Table`,T1.Type,T2.Description
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TableX T2 
ON T1.`Table` = 'X' AND T1.Type = 'B' AND T1.Type = T2.Type
UNION ALL
SELECT `Table`,T1.Type,T2.Description
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TableY T2 
ON T1.`Table` = 'Y' AND T1.Type = 'B' AND T1.Type = T2.Type
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40a3/6

```
SELECT `Table` as Project,Type,Description
FROM Table1 T1 WHERE Type = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Table`,T1.Type,T2.Description
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TableX T2 
ON T1.`Table` = 'X' AND T1.Type = 'B' AND T1.Type = T2.Type
AND T2.Description like CONCAT(T1.Description,"%")
UNION ALL
SELECT `Table`,T1.Type,T2.Description
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TableY T2 
ON T1.`Table` = 'Y' AND T1.Type = 'B' AND T1.Type = T2.Type
AND T2.Description like CONCAT(T1.Description,"%")
```

If you're trying to match description too you can use something like

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40a3/9

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between the 2 different codes? Also, A & B are just examples, the type is a dynamic value so a manual treatment won't help (plus there's also type2...). I guess I can merge it in both tables to, say, "type|description".

Comment: I forgot my train of thought...check sqlfiddle and see if it's the results you want.

Comment: your required result is strange and seem to be dependant on values A and B because it's long description half the time and it's just the short description half the time.

Comment: The external source data has a length limit, so sometimes it's cut off and sometimes it's not.